# upgraded to mac 10.6 - can't configure mysql

Tags: mysql, php, mac-osx

I'm new to mysql and I'm not a programmer. My computer is a Mac that has been upgraded to Snow Leopard. I have successfully installed apache2 and php, and I have downloaded and installed mySQL.

Problem: I can't configure mySQL to work with php.

When I type:

shell> cd /usr/local/mysql

in terminal I get

-bash: shell: command not found

I suspect it's a problem with the path, but as I'm not a programmer I don't know how to fix it.

I would be grateful for any help on this.

Comment: Are you typing _shell>_ before all your commands?

Comment: No, but I copied this command from a book I was following.

Comment: The `shell>` part in the book is used to symbolize your command prompt, as it is likely explained in your books introduction chapter. Don't type it.

Comment: Why are you installing all this stuff in the first place? Apache and PHP comes with MacOS and if that doesn't cut it, MAMP (http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) is a much better solution for testing purposes than trying to install everything yourself.

Comment: Now I get:  110322 13:46:12 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql-5.5.10-osx10.6-x86_64/data/angela-desvauxs-computer.local.err'.
grep: grep": No such file or directory
grep: 708: No such file or directory
grep: ": No such file or directory
110322 13:46:12 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql-5.5.10-osx10.6-x86_64/data
Does that look right to you?

Comment: Where do you get this messages? The grep part is an error message, but the rest looks OK, like the mysql daemon successfully started.

Comment: I'm setting up a test environment so that I can learn PHP and mySQL. PHP and Apache2, I only had to enable them. But mySQL didn't seem to be on the system. The last message I posted was from terminal as it appeared. I have now downloaded MAMP as you suggested.

Comment: Looks like MAMP is going to be MUCH easier. Thank you SO much. If only I'd asked earlier :)

Answer (score 1):

Try just typing

`mysql`

at the shell prompt.

Comment: Here are my tries and results so far: shell> cd /usr/local/mysql
-bash: shell: command not found
 mysql
-bash: mysql: command not found
 shell> cd mysql
-bash: shell: command not found
  Did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading from 10.5 to 10.6 normally breaks MySQL and requires a reinstall of the latest MySQL.